# Admin-LTE theme integration in yii2 & changing its default theme

Tags: yii2, themes, adminlte

I have integrated the AdminLTE theme in my web app now I want to change the theme of the AdminLTE from its default blue black to red color, How can I do this? In which files I need to make the required changes..?

Answer (score 3):

In My case I just change body class to

 

    <body class="skin-red"> 

in layouts/main.php

Answer (score 1):

`link rel="stylesheet" href="/adminlte/dist/css/skins/<strike>skin-blue</strike>.min.css"`

`body class="hold-transition <strike>skin-blue</strike> sidebar-mini"`

In the above, change this `skin-blue` with

options:

- skin-purple
- skin-yellow
- skin-red
- skin-green

Comment: Please check documentation https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/documentation/ for more options of the skin

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `dmstr` extension for this? If so set this in configuration:

```
'components' => [
    'assetManager' => [
        'bundles' => [
            'dmstr\web\AdminLteAsset' => [
                'skin' => 'skin-red',
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

and then in layout add

```
<body class="<?= \dmstr\helpers\AdminLteHelper::skinClass() ?>">
```

If you are not using this extension or just don't want to play with config file add the proper class name in layout's body like:

```
<body class="skin-red">
```

Just make sure you have got proper css file in `dist/css/skins` folder.

Comment: In other word, if I want to add new color skin, then I have to add my css to dist/css/skins folder? for example I want to add teal.